# How to do unions from different tables in QueryDSL

Tags: querydsl

my question is simple how can I select from different tables using SQL QueryDSL
for example

```
SELECT cat.name as name, cat.voice as voice , cat.purr FROM cat UNION
SELECT dog.name as name, dog.voice as voice , NULL as voice FROM dog;
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've posted, other than the fact you've used the same column alias twice in your second SELECT?

Comment: my question on how to do it in QueryDSL, because i couldn't fin any docs in the official site

Comment: And my question is *What's wrong with what you've posted here?* Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: I don't know there is doc to implement such as example using aliases

Comment: Again, I didn't ask if you found documentation. **I asked **What's wrong with what you posted here? Did you try it? Does it work?** What part of that is difficult for you to understand?

Comment: You don't know how to run a query in QueryDSL at all?

Comment: Just some simple queries, i'm still in the precess of learining

Comment: If you can run any queries, you can try to run this one and see what happens. SELECT can't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
QCat cat = QCat.cat;
QDog dog = QDog.dog;

StringPath name = Expressions.stringPath("name");
StringPath voice = Expressions.stringPath("voice");
StringPath purr = Expressions.stringPath("purr");

SQLQueryFactory queryFactory = new SQLQueryFactory(MySQLTemplates.DEFAULT, null);
SQLQuery<Tuple> cats =
    SQLExpressions.select(cat.nome.as(name), cat.voice.as(voice), cat.purr.as(purr)).from(cat);
SQLQuery<Tuple> dogs =
    SQLExpressions.select(
            dog.nome.as(name),
            dog.voice.as(voice),
            Expressions.as(Expressions.nullExpression(), purr))
        .from(dog);
queryFactory.select(name, voice, purr).from(SQLExpressions.union(cats, dogs)).fetch();
```